# Alternatives to base tag

Tags: html, url-rewriting

I used mode rewrite on my website

I used the base tag to solve my relative links problem

```
<base href="/" />
```

But the problem is absolute link eg. http://www.absolutelinks.com

It changes it to www.mysite.com/http://www.absolutelinks.com

How can i fix this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Base href* applies only to the relative URL so if you have got: `<a href="http://google.com/">Google</a>` you'll be redirected to Google, not `http://mydomain/http://google.com/`. Please post the code of your HTML document.

However using `base` isn't the best practice. Much better approach is to use absolute URLs like: `src="/styles/main.css"` which **always** points to `mydomain/styles/main.css`.

Comment: but take care that if your website resides in a folder thhe "/style/main.css" wan't do it, e.g. http://www.mydomain.com/newtest/index.html, the src="/styles.main.css" will look for the css file in the root folder. I think the best practice is to use a config file to set the full path of your domain + path

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `<base>` at all, instead have some server-side config and keep a $base variable there - then, when outputting any URL during your HTML generation use {$base}{$restofurl}.

This works well when you have the same code running in development/test/live environments - you just need to change your server-side $base config.

Using PHP/Smarty syntax above but I'm sure you get the idea.